# LibreOffice Writer: Push a table one line downwards, when it is in the first line of your document

Tags: libreoffice

I have a document to which I inserted a table. I inserted that table to the **first line** of the document.

The current state is that I can't locate the writing cursor on the first line, because it is occupied by the cursor.

---

[image]

---

Is there a way to push the table down without cutting and pasting it, so that the cursor could be putted in the first line regularly?

<sub>BTW, I had a similar issue in Microsoft Word.</sub>

### Update for Jim K:

Jim, this is the file (link omitted) in which standing with the cursor in the first cell of the first row of the first column (just before the email address) and hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> results in pushing the entire table to the next page instead just one line down (that's what I get in LO Writer 6.0.1.1 at least). I couldn't reproduce this in a similar brand new file. Also, note one cannot mark everything with hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, in that file.

Comment: Have you considered the solutions contained here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/257/how-can-i-move-tables-in-writer/

Comment: I mentioned I considered cutting and pasting but I don't ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the cursor is located at the start of the first cell of the table, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You might need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead.

This is mentioned in the link posted by @Graham, although you have to read far down through the answers because that is not quite the same question.

**EDIT**:

To completely fix the table in the example file, after inserting the new line, go to *Table -> Properties -> Text Flow* and uncheck *Text Flow / Break*.

Or this can be done graphically while in *View -> Web* mode.

[image: delete page break]

Comment: I actually already read that answer there but to be honest, and not sarcastic, I really don't see how it does what I wanted --- I desire to Push the table just one line downwards, not to the next page.

Comment: It should not push to the next page unless the table takes up the whole page.  If it does, perhaps you need to split it into two tables or modify page flow settings.  Perhaps you're confusing it with `Ctrl+Enter` which inserts a page break?  `Alt+Enter` simply inserts one line above the table.

Comment: Funny, what you just described worked with an empty table but not with a table that already contains text and a sub table.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, I just now created a table with text and an inner table and it still works.  So either give steps to reproduce the problem or else post a link to an example document.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Jim, I think the process is even shorter and I've tested it with several files: When I clicked "Alt+Enter" when in the start of the first cell I didn't always get the desired result. But when it was just "Enter" without the "Alt", I did get the desired result (pushing the entire table just one line down). You might want to ensure that yourself and edit accordingly (change from "Alt+Enter" to just "Enter").